# Perl - SHA1 not matching PHP

Tags: php, perl, md5, sha1

My experience in perl is lacking. But, from what I read online and have seen googling this problem; perl's md5, sha1, sha256 ... should be returning the same hash as php or any other language, but aren't.

is there something I'm misunderstanding or missing?

**Perl Code:** (v5.14.2)

```
use Digest::SHA 'sha1_hex';
print Digest::SHA->sha1_hex("test");
# outputs e2412033b6d0070b931d01b0d1783b937608eb7f
```

**PHP Code:** (v5.4)

```
echo sha1("test");
//outputs: a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
```

Comment: `$ perl -MDigest::SHA=sha1_hex -E 'say sha1_hex("test")'` yields `a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your program should look like:

```
use Digest::SHA 'sha1_hex';
print sha1_hex("test");
```

or

```
use Digest::SHA;
print Digest::SHA::sha1_hex("test"); # note ::
```

When you call `Digest::SHA->sha1_hex("test");`, you're using so called <strike>"indirect object" notation</strike>, which is equivalent to `sha1_hex("Digest::SHA", "test")`· That's why you get different hash:

```
use Digest::SHA 'sha1_hex';
say sha1_hex("Digest::SHAtest")
# -> e2412033b6d0070b931d01b0d1783b937608eb7f
```

Comment: Actually that's a direct method call, not indirect object notation. Indirect object notation is `my $result = methodname $object @arguments`, while a standard (direct) method call is like `my $result = $object->method(@arguments)`. But in this case neither is desired because `sha1_hex` is a function rather than a method.